# Akka streams: how to use backoff strategy only in case of failure?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a rather complex Source `source`, which I've wrapped into Backoff to be able to restart the stream in case of failure:

```
val backoffSource = RestartSource.withBackoff(settings){() => source}
```

I link this source to the sink, which has a materialized value `Future[Done]`:

```
val future = backoffSource.toMat(sink)(Keep.right).run()
```

After that in case of success of this graph I want do some actions when the graph is finished. So, I want to do somethink like:

```
future.onComplete{
  case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
  case Success(_) => println("Success")
}
```

But as per documentation `RestartSource`  is

> starting an operator again when it fails or completes, each time with a growing time delay between restarts

So my graph will keep restarting until `maxRestarts` is reached.

How can I implement the next behaviour:

1. Backoff strategy will be applied only in case of failure
2. In case of graph's success It will call my `onComplete` method with `Success(_)`
3. In case of `maxRestarts` failures the `onComplete` with `Failure(_)` will be called
   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/RestartSource$.html#onFailuresWithBackoff%5BT%5D(settings:akka.stream.RestartSettings)(sourceFactory:()=%3Eakka.stream.scaladsl.Source%5BT,_%5D):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source%5BT,akka.NotUsed%5D):

> Wrap the given Source with a Source that will restart it when it fails using an exponential backoff.

From inspection of the source, if the wrapped `Source` fails enough to fail overall, the stream will fail with the exception from the last failure.